# Div cant work with height auto or 100%

Tags: css, html, height

i've been looking for some time here and still can't find a fix for my problem.

I'm trying to build a site where i have 1 main div with 2 div's making a 2 column, the problem is: I want the main div to recognize the height from them and auto adjust, to keep it perfect. But my main div just ignore everything and my site gets all weird.

Also, here is my test page, so you can see what i'm talking about: http://dayzsa.bl.ee/

Here is my code so far:

```
CSS
body {margin:0; }
div.header {
    width:100%;
    height:90px;
    margin:0;
    background:#CCC;}

div.content {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    min-height:350px;
    max-height:500px;
    margin:0;
    border-bottom:1px dotted #000;
    background:#999; }

div.footer {
    background:#333;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    max-height:250px;
    min-height:200px;
    margin:0; }

div.content-company {
    width:100%;
    min-width:900px;
    max-width:1400px;
    margin:0 auto;
    height:100%;
    padding:25px 15px;
    background:#C90; }

div.content-company-left {
    width:51%;
    padding:0 25px;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    text-align:justify;
    background:#300; }

div.content-company-right {
    width:45%;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    background:#F6F; }

HTML

<div class="header"><!-- menu goes in here --></div>
<div class="content">
    <div class="content-company">
        <div class="content-company-left">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="content-company-right"><img src="img.png" border="none" width="100%" /></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="footer"><!--footer goes in here -->
```

If anyone knows how to help me, i thank you.

Answer (score 0):

use `overflow:auto` in class `.content-company`.

Answer (score 0):

Add float in your main div css rule:

```
div.content-company { float:left }
```

and there is no need to add `height:100%`